# introducing records on the fly in mysql

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

Is it possible in MySQL to create records on the fly without first having to create a temporary table and then populate it?

I'm thinking about something like this (syntactically incorrect) example:

```
SELECT * FROM (`id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, "FOO"),
(2, "BAR");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it this way -

```
SELECT 1 id, 'FOO' value
  UNION
SELECT 2 id, 'BAR' value
```